# PHP script as windows service

Tags: php, windows, service

I have a launch.bat file:

```
@echo off
c:\xampp\php\php.exe -f "c:\telegram_bot\main.php"
```

In main.php there is e while(true) cycle thet get update from telegram bot.
If I start launch.bat file with double click work perfect.

I create a windows service to start the script but when I start service I have this error:

"Error 1053: The Service did not Respond to the Start or Control Request in a Timely Fashion"

I think this depend of while(true) cycle.
Any idea.

Tks

Comment: See this: [Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/services).

Comment: you shouldn't do that, if you want to hide console window use `RBClick` tool (hides to tray) or `ConEmu`

Answer (score 0):

A service is different that a .exe. Requires some tasks as always responds as keep live.
Read this article to run any exe as service.
https://www.howtogeek.com/50786/using-srvstart-to-run-any-application-as-a-windows-service/